# Is there any other nmcli connect implementation that uses ifname as input? Current implementation adds a number postfix to SSID

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I have created a C++ wrapper on top of `nmcli` to connect 2 WiFi modules to WPA2 networks in Ubuntu 18. However, it adds a number postfix to the SSID.
Example: `My Network` becomes `My Network 1` and then this number keeps growing.

As I need to specify the `ifname`, the current command is
`nmcli -w 90 device wifi connect BSSID password AMAZING_PASSWORD ifname wlan0`. I have also tried using `nmcli connection up <name> ifname <my_interface>`, but that requires me to actually connect both WiFi modules to the network previously, but that does not seem right. Are there any solutions that would avoid that number postfix or an easier way to implement the `connection up` without needing to previously connect both modules to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the connection name when connecting using:

```
#wlan0
nmcli -w 90 device wifi connect BSSID password AMAZING_PASSWORD ifname wlan0 name NAME_OF_CON_VIA_WLAN0
# wlan1
nmcli -w 90 device wifi connect BSSID password AMAZING_PASSWORD ifname wlan1 name NAME_OF_CON_VIA_WLAN1
```

You can see your list of connections using `nmcli c`. By default when connecting to a wifi network the SSID is also the connection name but you can change it

Comment: Fair enough. But then, I would need to connect both modules to the network.
I mean, this approach requires me to develop code also to check whether the system has already been connected to his network before or not. I was searching for a solution in which I could connect only one WiFi module and use that information to connect the other one when necessary.

Comment: I don't quite understand, but you can delete the connection like so: `nmcli connection delete NAME_OF_CON` , and then you can add or delete connection according to your logic

Comment: Do you mean that I should always delete a connection after I disconnect from it?

Comment: I don't know all the pros and cons of create/delete connection vs up/down of an existing connection. But deleting a connection is a valid and good solution for many use-cases